# Issue with InStr and Left to return right text from string

Tags: string, excel, vba, iban

I am playing around with some IBAN/SWIFT codes that I have in a `string` in Excel VBA, but I would like to just pick the IBAN number out of the string.

Samples:
   **DK4520005010201483** IBAN NDEADKKKXXX
    **NL24ABNA0424079763** iban ABNANL2A
    **DE56300700100303808000** IBAN DEUTDEDD

The string(s) from above is saved in the string `iban`
Code:

```
Dim cutDownStr as String, iban as string

cutDownStr = iban
fooStr = Left(cutDownStr, (Len(cutDownStr) - InStr(cutDownStr, " ")))
MsgBox fooStr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your code was cutting the length of the IBAN from the whole string. You needed to cut the length of the string AFTER the IBAN, including the space. You can do that with:

```
fooStr = Left(cutDownStr, (Len(cutDownStr) - (Len(cutDownStr) - InStr(cutDownStr, " "))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the substring preceding *iban* then:

```
Sub qwerty()
  iban = "DK4520005010201483 IBAN NDEADKKKXXX"
  foostr = Split(iban, " ")(0)
  MsgBox foostr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you :) I ended up going with the marked answer, as it was helping me to better understand the issue. Thanks for the answer tho.

Answer (score 1):

**Using a function**

```
Function findIban(iban as String)
  fooStr = split(iban," ")
  findIban = fooStr(0) 
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
Dim cutDownStr as String

cutDownStr = "DK4520005010201483 IBAN NDEADKKKXXX"
fooStr = findIban(cutDownStr)
MsgBox fooStr
```

Comment: Thank you :) I ended up going with the marked answer, as it was helping me to better understand the issue. Thanks for the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

InstrRev is a cool function if your String is not really well delimited, say in the example that the IBAN part is sometimes 10 char and sometimes 8 char.  InstrRev gives you the character count (from the left) like Instr does, but it searches the string from the right. When searching for "/" in "/John/Son" the result is 6 NOT 1.  From there you could use the Right Function.

```
    Sub IBANiac
    Dim IBAN1, FindIBAN as String
    IBAN1 = "DK4520005010201483 IBAN NDEADKKKXXX"
    findIBAN = right(IBAN1,len(IBAN1)-instrrev(_
    IBAN1,"IBAN ",-1,vbtextcompare))
    msgbox findIBAN
    'May want to add a +-1 to the second part of the right _
    function to account for spacing
    End Sub
```